# How can I delete in-game save files on an Android DS emulator without multi-touch?

Tags: pokemon-series, emulation, pokemon-fourth-generation

I'm using a DS emulator to play games on an old Android phone (Jellybean) that doesn't support input with more than two fingers at a time. This is ok most of the time, however certain games require you to press 3 or more buttons for certain actions.

In this case, I'm trying to delete the in-game save for Pokemon Platinum, which requires me to press <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Select</kbd>, and <kbd>B</kbd> on the Title screen, impossible to do on my device.

I also cannot simply start a new game: as a form of protection for your save files, Platinum prevents you from overwriting the old save file with a new one.

How can I delete this save file without pressing 3 places on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

The Android file system is browseable using a File Explorer app. Most devices include one by default, but if not, you should be able to find one on the Google Play Store.

Without knowing the exact DS Emulator you're using, it's hard to give a precise file path,  but there's two places to check:

- The folder named after the DS emulator's name
- The folder containing your ROM (which could be your 'Downloads' folder if you haven't moved it).

Either case, in one of these locations, there is likely a save file with the same name as the ROM - it might have a `.sav` extension. If you move, delete or rename this file, the game save should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't load a save state, you would be on the platinum loading screen, yes? If you want to delete it to start a new file, simply press new game and use the game's built in save feature to overwrite your current one.

Should you want to entirely remove your game, you would want to go into your phone's file browser and delete it manually.  Hope this helps!

Comment: The first half of this answer is flat-out wrong.  For most generations, you cannot overwrite a saved game with a new one (likely little brother ignorance protection)